# How to test if an object is disposed and GC'ed?

Tags: c#, testing, garbage-collection

I'm writing some code to delete an object and wanted to have a unit test to ensure that the object is always deleted. What is the best way to do this? If GC is to work you should not be holding any references so how can you test without a reference?

Comment: *"[...] ensure that the object is always deleted"* How do you control *when* the garbage collector collects your object, then?

Comment: The intent is to determine if the object in question is the cause of a memory leak...

Comment: Are you talking about leaking memory from managed heap, or leaking memory from unmanaged heap (if that is case for you)?

Comment: You cannot "delete an object" so there's nothing to test here either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to test if object is disposed in general case.

[WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is probably the thing you are looking for. You can create a WeakReference as part of the test and after your code has run this:

```
WeakReference wr = new WeakReference(obj);
GC.Collect();
Assert.IsTrue(!wr.IsAlive);
```